# How to delete elements of an array after a specified index

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to remove the elements of an array that have an index greater than, or equal to a specified index value.

```
int values[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int size_of_array = 7;
int specified_index = 3;

for(int i = size_of_array; i >= specified_index; size_of_array--){
  values[middle_index + 1] = NULL;
}
```

I am very new to C so it is still a little confusing. Apologies if this is duplicate.

Comment: "Apologies", don't be sorry but do perform basic search for an answer before asking a new question.

Comment: if you track the elements in an array with size_of_array.... just do `size_of_array = 3`  done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot resize an array in C. Once it is created its size is fixed.
If you are OK to use dynamic memory and a pointer instead of an array you could resize it using [`realloc`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/realloc.html).

However looking at your purposes you don't actually need to resize the array, you can just decrease `size_of_array` and ignore the remaining values, eg:

```
size_of_array -= 4;
```

**Edit:**
To clarify what I mean by ignoring values. I assume that by creating an array you intend to actually so some work with its elements, else having the array would be pointless. Therefore when you do your work on the array, just only do it on elements which you are not ignoring. Let us for the sake of example say we want to print the values of the array as our "work":

```
void printArray(int *array, size_t size) {
    for (size_t itr = 0; itr < size; ++itr) { printf("%d", array[itr])); }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int values[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    int size_of_array = 7;
    int specified_index = 3;
    // Print the whole array
    printArray(values, size_of_array);
    // Print the 'shortened' array by ignoring the rest of the values
    size_of_array -= 4;
    printArray(values, size_of_array);
}
```

Comment: How does this get rid of the values equal to or greater than the 3rd index? Wouldn't this leave me with the 1st 3 elements?

Comment: It does not "get rid" of any values, as I said, doing so is impossible with an array in C. Instead, you can simply ignore them, yes, they will still exist in memory but as long as you only do your work on the first 3 elements, what does it matter if more exist if you ignore them?

Comment: Ok, then how does this ignore the values greater than or equal to the specified_index?

Comment: Let me add a small example to show what I mean.

Comment: I think I know what you mean, I would change the size_of_array and then have to change where the starting_index is correct?

Comment: @rebbailey Does that edit clear it up? You can probably actually run that code assuming I didn't typo to see that it works.